# Pandas, taking sum of the elements for which all three values in rows are available

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have a dataframe like this:

```
Country   Year    Orange  Apple Plump
US        2008    17      29     19
US        2009    11      12     16
US        2010    14      16     38
Spain     2008    11      NULL   33
Spain     2009    12      19     17
France    2008    17      19     21
France    2009    19      22     13
France    2010    12      11     15
Italy     2009    NULL    NULL   PRIVATE
Italy     2010    15      16     17
Italy     2011    42      NULL   PRIVATE
```

First, I want to get the mean value of the rows, but I only want to consider rows for which all orange, apple, plump information is available

Second, I am trying to get the max difference between different fruits (e.g. for US for the year 2008 it is 12), if at least only one information for fruit is available. For instance for italy 2011 it will be 42

Third I wanna repeat the same for countries who have information for all of the years between 2008 -2010.
Any help will be highly appriciated

Comment: The first thing I would worry about: it seems you can not have integers and `NaN` in a single column. `NaN` can only live together with floats in the same column. Is that an issue? How did you generated your current DataFrame?

Comment: oh actually I made up my values as real data frame is quite complicated. Now I update it

Comment: So `NULL` and `PRIVATE` are strings here?!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately they are strings...

Comment: I understand the first two requirements, but what do you mean by `repaad`.

Comment: sorry yes I mean repeat

Comment: ah, okay :) got it

Comment: When I see all the answers and consider your question I wonder if it wouldn't make more sense to give up the DataFrame and just use a list of dictionaries instead.

Comment: Indeed I load the data from csv and it i very large...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

cols = ['Country', 'Year', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']

data = [['US', 2008, 17, 29, 19],
        ['US', 2009, 11, 12, 16],
        ['US', 2010, 14, 16, 38],
        ['Spain', 2008, 11, None, 33],
        ['Spain', 2009, 12, 19, 17],
        ['France', 2008, 17, 19, 21],
        ['France', 2009, 19, 22, 13],
        ['France', 2010, 12, 11, 15],
        ['Italy', 2009, None, None, None],
        ['Italy', 2010, 15, 16, 17],
        ['Italy', 2011, 42, None, None]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

df['Any_NaN'] = df.apply(lambda row: any(np.isnan(r) for r in row['Orange':'Plump']), axis=1)
df['Any_number'] = df.apply(lambda row: any(not np.isnan(r) for r in row['Orange':'Plump']), axis=1)

df['Average'] = df[['Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']].mean(axis=1)

df['Max'] = df[['Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']].max(axis=1)
df['Min'] = df[['Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']].min(axis=1)
df['Max_diff'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Max'] - row['Min'], axis=1)
df['Desired_avg'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.nan if row['Any_NaN'] else row['Average'], axis=1)

print df
```

Output

```
   Country  Year  Orange  Apple  Plump Any_NaN Any_number    Average   Max   Min  Max_diff  Desired_avg
0       US  2008    17.0   29.0   19.0   False       True  21.666667  29.0  17.0      12.0    21.666667
1       US  2009    11.0   12.0   16.0   False       True  13.000000  16.0  11.0       5.0    13.000000
2       US  2010    14.0   16.0   38.0   False       True  22.666667  38.0  14.0      24.0    22.666667
3    Spain  2008    11.0    NaN   33.0    True       True  22.000000  33.0  11.0      22.0          NaN
4    Spain  2009    12.0   19.0   17.0   False       True  16.000000  19.0  12.0       7.0    16.000000
5   France  2008    17.0   19.0   21.0   False       True  19.000000  21.0  17.0       4.0    19.000000
6   France  2009    19.0   22.0   13.0   False       True  18.000000  22.0  13.0       9.0    18.000000
7   France  2010    12.0   11.0   15.0   False       True  12.666667  15.0  11.0       4.0    12.666667
8    Italy  2009     NaN    NaN    NaN    True      False        NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN          NaN
9    Italy  2010    15.0   16.0   17.0   False       True  16.000000  17.0  15.0       2.0    16.000000
10   Italy  2011    42.0    NaN    NaN    True       True  42.000000  42.0  42.0       0.0          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

first it is necessary to clean up the data, convert to the correct types & fill any null values as required. *in this example, we don't require any filling*

for col in ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plump']:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], 'coerce')

The 2nd argument to the [`pandas.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) function defines how error values are to be handled.

Then we can apply a function row-wise to achieve the desired result.

the function should accept a Series with the dataframe's column names as key, apply the logic, and return a tuple, which forms the additional columns.

```
df[['fruitmean', 'fruitdiff']] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

where we defined `myfunc` as follows:

```
def myfunc(x):
    vals = pd.Series([x.Apple, x.Orange, x.Plump])
    valfilled = vals.fillna(0)
    nulls = vals.isnull().sum()
    fruitmean = vals.mean() if nulls == 0 else np.nan
    fruitdiff = valfilled.max() - valfilled.min() if nulls < len(vals) else np.nan
    return pd.Series([fruitmean, fruitdiff])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As its mentioned in the comments, the numbers are strings and difficult to convert to int due to characters like PRIVATE, to_numeric(errors = 'coerce') takes care of that.
2. Convert year to datetime so that it doesn't come in the way of calculations later.
3. Pandas mean still finds the mean by ignoring one or two cells with NaN. So the condition in np.where tried to find if the boolean sum of three columns Orange, Apple and Plum is 3 or not. If yes, find mean, else return Nan

   df[['Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']] = df[['Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')

   df.Year = pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format = '%Y')

   df['mean'] = np.where(df[['Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']].notnull().sum(axis = 1) == 3, df.mean(axis =1).round(2), np.nan)

   df['max_diff'] = df[['Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0).max()-x.fillna(0).min(), axis = 1)